# Bit format conversion using bit-manipulation operators

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have a bit conversion problem that I am a bit struggling with.  A bit of background... working on some computation biology problems and so need to to be supper fast (dealing with massive data sets).  Basically I have the following bit representation of SNP's and I want to write some mask/and/xor/etc. operations so that I can quickly convert from one representation to the next:

00 -> 100

01 -> 010

11 -> 001

So for example 00010111 should convert to 100010010001.  I am storing the bits in a rather large java.util.BitSet and would idealy like to be able to convert them to the new format just using bit operators.

Any help would be very welcome!

Comment: You need to describe more about how conversion works.  Pattern matching? Streaming?  We need more info.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do these words get larger than 64 bits?  If so I'm not sure you'll be happy with a bit-manipulation based solution.  Have you tried [ropes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29) ?

Comment: Well right now I am doing it manually, as in for every two bits and add 3 bits two a separate BitSet.  However, this process is fairly slow.  I have been trying to modify the procedure to allow me to perform some bitwise operation on the entier BitSet at once that will produce the new format.

Comment: Have you run a profiler?  I would recommend trying that before you redesign anything, just to be sure there's no funny business going on that might be affecting the performance.  My favorite free one is jvisualvm.

Comment: Another idea - use lookup tables for the bit conversion.  You could even expand the lookup tables to expand each 4 bits into 6, etc, if something is still slow.

Comment: Aye I have... there are a lot of slow points I am working on.  But even if I can just design a mask to manipulate two bits to three it will shave off quit a bit of time.

Comment: Hmm the look up is actually a good idea.  Thanks Rob!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a lookup table.  Grab 16 bits at a time and look them up in a 64K table with 24 bit entries.

```
int[] table = new int[65536];
table[0] = 0b100100100100100100100100;
table[1] = 0b100100100100100100100010;
...
table[65535] = 0b001001001001001001001001;
BitSet output = new BitSet();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 16) {
    int x = (input.get(i) ? 1 : 0)
          + (input.get(i+1) ? 2 : 0)
          ...
          + (input.get(i+15) ? 32768 : 0);
    int y = table[x];
    output.set(i/16*24, (y & 1) != 0);
    output.set(i/16*24 + 1, ((y>>1) & 1) != 0);
    ...
    output.set(i/16*24 + 23, ((y>>23) & 1) != 0);
}
```